# Get file name list in fileinfo list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

How can i get file name list from

```
List<FileInfo> FileInfoList;
```

by using LINQ? I want all file names in

```
List<string> FileNames;
```

list. I don't want to construct a foreach loop and don't want to add file names iteratively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) extension method:

```
List<string> FileNames = FileInfoList.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

However, if you don't really need it to be a `List<T>`, you can probably take advantage of Linq's lazy-execution ability by simply omitting the `ToList` method:

```
IEnumerable<string> FileNames = FileInfoList.Select(x => x.Name);
```

Or if you prefer query syntax:

```
IEnumerable<string> FileNames = from x in FileInfoList select x.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the FileNames in FileNames list, try:

```
FileInfoList.ForEach(x => 
            FileNames.Add(Path.GetFileName(x.FullName)));
```

If you want complete file paths in FileNames try

```
FileInfoList.ForEach(x => 
            FileNames.Add(x.FullName));
```